# How to roll-back a shell command once executed?

Tags: command-line

I would like to know if there is a way to roll-back shell commands : for example rolling back a `rm -rf` command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to "roll back" shell commands.

If you removed a file using `rm` command, you can only try to restore it using [testdisk or a similar software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files).

Some of shell commands can be rolled back by other shell commands.

For example, if `file.txt` did not exist, command

```
echo "bla bla bla" > file.txt
```

can be rolled back by

```
rm file.txt
```

If `file.txt` had some content, the first command can't be rolled back.

**So you need to be very careful using shell commands!**

Comment: A way of no return :) I understand your answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

In general, a shell command could do *anything* to the system, and there is no omnipotent undo mechanism within Ubuntu.

However, if you run Ubuntu as a guest inside a virtual machine, you could take a snapshot of the virtual machine, which would give you the ability to rollback to the snapshot.